# How do I implement the fnv1a hash function on a string which is in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable, hash-function

I'm trying to implement the fnv1a hash function on all the words from a dictionary (so I can access them quickly later on).

This is the fnv1a hash function:

```
int
fnv1a(unsigned char byte, uint32_t hash)
{
    hash = SEED;
    // SEED is a constant that I defined
    return ((byte ^ hash) * PRIME) % HASHTABLE_SIZE;
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to get the hash for a word in a function called load():

```
int hash = fnv1a((unsigned char)*(ptr->word)++, SEED);
```

Here's the full function:

/*
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

```
bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{    
    FILE* fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");

    // make new node to store the stuff in
    node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->next = NULL;

    // while it's not the end of the file
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        // store the word in the ptr
        fscanf(fp, "%s", ptr->word);

        // get hash function for word
        int hash = fnv1a((unsigned char)*(ptr->word)++, SEED);

        // store word at hash value in hashtable

        // if there isn't a word there yet
        if (hashtable[hash]->next == NULL) 
            hashtable[hash]->next = ptr;  

    // else go to the end of the list and add the word

    // haven't done this part yet

    if (hashtable == NULL)
    {
        printf("Didn't work out, bud");
        return false;
    }   

    else 
        return true;
}
```

The error that I keep getting when I compile this code (points to the line with me trying to hash a word):

```
dictionary.c:70:53: error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

Comment: @TonyTheLion It won't compile. Sorry I forgot to note that, but you can see the error at the bottom of my question now :)

Comment: what's the type of `word` in `ptr->word`?

Comment: @TonyTheLion It seems it's `char []`.

Comment: `char[]` don't have `operator++` defined on them.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the type of `ptr->word` is an array of `char`, or `char []`. You can't increment an array, change design.

Comment: so if I declared it as a char *, would that fix the problem?

Comment: @teektaks If it's a pointer, it can be incremented, but then you would have to dynamically allocate memory before `fscanf()`'ing a string into it. But really, Thony The Lion's solution is just fine. Grab a pointer to the first element of the array and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply solve your problem like so:

```
char* ptr = &ptr->word[0];

fnv1a(*ptr++, SEED);
```

Comment: Can you write it like this: char* ptr = ptr->word[0] instead of &ptr->word[0] ? Do we need the ampersand operator?

Comment: & is the address of operator, and yes you need it in this case.